# Uploading files, Firefox, Chrome work but not IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the following code which allows a user to browse for an image on thier local devive and select it for upload.

The code works perfectly in Firefox 49.x and Chrome 49.x but not in IE 9.x.

The code does have an "addEventListener" as a part of it which looks to see if the browser supports file uplaod.

When using IE 9.x and try to select a file for uplaod the code issues an error "File upload not support by your browser". That error massage is in the code below but does nayone know why IE will not work.

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var elBrowse = document.getElementById("browse"),
    elPreview = document.getElementById("preview2"),
    useBlob = false && window.URL; // `true` to use Blob instead of      Data-URL

function readImage(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var image = new Image();

        image.addEventListener("load", function() {
            if (image.height >= 390) {
                var imageInfo = '<br><br>Your selected file size is<br>  Display width ' +
                    image.width + ',px <br> Display height ' +
                    image.height + 'px ' + '';

                elPreview.appendChild(this);
                elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", imageInfo + '<br>');
                $("#resetfile").show();
            } else {
                $("#image_field").val('');
                $("#preview2").val('');
                alert(file.name + '\n\n Selected image is to small\n Display width ' + image.width + ',\n Display height ' + image.height + ' \n\n Please change the image size');
            }
        });
        image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
        if (useBlob) {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file);
        }
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var files = this.files;
    var errors = "";
    if (!files) {
        errors += "File upload not supported by your browser.";
    }
    if (files && files[0]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if ((/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name)) {
                readImage(file);
            } else {
                errors += file.name + " Unsupported Image extension\n";
            }
        }
    }
    if (errors) {
        alert(errors);
    }
});
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Your use of `FileReader` is an issue as it's only supported in IE10+

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks for your reply, is there a way around it?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) you can use the [FileAPI](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/fileapi/fileapi/info) polyfill